# SQL - How do I create a linkage table?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I'm building the following data model in Django / SQL

```
Table 1 (Entity) - things that can do things
Entity ID:
Enum: (Person, or Business)

Table 2 (Person)
Entity ID:
Person ID:
Firstname
Lastname

Table 3 (Ltd Co.)
Entity ID:
Ltd Co. ID:
Company Name
Company No.
```

I'm trying to link a Person, who has a Limited Co., with an Agent (who is also a Person) that also has a Limited Co. So 4 different entitites, two of which are type Person, and two of which are type Limited Co.

Do I need another Linkage Table? E.g.

| Profile Person | Profile Ltd Co | Agent Person | Agent Ltd Co |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entity 1: Type = Person | Entity 3: Type = Business | Entity 2: Type = Person | Entity 4: Type = Business |

**Q. How do I create this Linkage Table in a Django Model / or SQL?**

**Q. Is a Linkage Table the right approach?**

UPDATE

Here are snippets from my model.py

```
class Entity(models.Model):

    class EntityTypes(models.TextChoices):
        PERSON = 'Person', _('Person')
        COMPANY = 'Company', _('Company')

    entity_type = models.CharField(
                verbose_name='Legal Entity Type', 
                max_length=7, 
                choices=EntityTypes.choices, 
                default=EntityTypes.PERSON, 
                blank=False, 
                null=False)


class Person(models.Model):
    related_entity  = models.OneToOneField(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name      = models.CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)



class LtdCo(models.Model):
    related_entity  = models.OneToOneField(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name      = models.CharField(verbose_name='Company Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    company_no       = models.CharField(verbose_name='Company No.', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Could you share your `models.py`?

Comment: I've added the 3 tables, as I've written them in Django so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `ForeignKey`. You can link one `Person` object to another one. Just add this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    agent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='clients')
```

From now on, you can simply add one `Person` as an `agent` in another `Person`'s field. Usage:

```
person_1 = Person.objects.create(...)
person_2 = Person.objects.create(..., agent=person_1)

person_1.clients.all()
# <QuerySet [<Person: Person 2>]>

person_2 in person_1.clients.all()
# True

person_2.agent
# <Person: Person 1>

person_2.agent.related_entity.entity_type
# 'Company' / 'Person'
```

You can access related object by simple `.agent` or reverse relation of all clients with the `related_name` you want to use, in my example it's `.clients`. Just remember, that reverse relation is always a `QuerySet`, because one agent can have many clients, but every client can have one agent. Relationhips are very powerful in Django, follow this [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/) for details.

Comment: Thanks Nixon! This is really helpful. But I do wonder, how I connect Ltd Co's to Persons with Profiles, or Ltd Co's to Persons who are Agents..would adding another separate linkage table, not just be the most logical/flexible solution? I say this, because the Linkage Table might grow, and there may be a model I need to add for say, Sole Trader - which would be an Entity of Type = 'Business', so I would need to link: Persons to Multiple Entities (through which that person functions), and then at most, a Normal Person to an Agent Person

Comment: So the rules are. 1. An Entity of type = 'Person' should link to 'multiple' Entities of type = 'Business', and then  2) I should be able ot link an Entity of type = 'Person' to at least one other Entity of type = 'Person', for which i thought a sepate linkage table might be the best approach...?

Comment: Sorry, but your following questions are too broad. You have to think yourself about your app structure :) We can help you with specific questions/problems and only 1 at a time. Read the docs I've sent you, that will be much helpful. Also, please, tick my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Ok, I've ticked your answer as helpful. I think the solution I am looking for actually is an intermediary table, which I believe Django Docs supports. I'm reading through their documentation now.