# Page not found at/admin

Tags: django

I'm a very beginner.
When I tried to go visit this (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin), I couldn't. Here have shown page not found. What can be the solution?

**Problem that I faced:**

```
Page not found (404)
“D:\1_WebDevelopment\Business_Website\admin” does not exist
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
Using the URLconf defined in business_website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
admin/
[name='index']
singup [name='handle_singUp']
login [name='handle_login']
logout [name='handle_logout']
contact [name='handle_contact']
frontend_orders [name='frontend_orders']
hire_me [name='hire_me']
^(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, admin, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**Problem :** [open the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE5e9.png)

**business_website urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('business_app.urls')),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**business_website url.py :** [open the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fazuH.png)

**business_app urls.py:**

```
from os import name
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('singup', views.handle_singUp, name= "handle_singUp"),
    path('login', views.handle_login, name="handle_login"),
    path('logout', views.handle_logout, name="handle_logout"),
    path('contact', views.handle_contact, name="handle_contact"),
    path('frontend_orders', views.frontend_orders, name="frontend_orders"),
    path('hire_me', views.hire_me, name="hire_me")

]
```

**business_app url.py :** [open the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ABaZ.png)

Comment: Please share code. Especially `urls.py` and error.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('business_app.urls')),

]

Comment: Firstfully, add the code to the main question, don't write it in comment. Another thing - include also your business urls, views and settings.

Comment: @NixonSparrow please now see the question I added two photos of url.py

Comment: don't add pictures. Copy and paste your code in proper format. Here you have example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284923/sql-how-do-i-create-a-linkage-table/71285418#71285418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete from `business_app urls.py` this row:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

You should not call it twice.

You should set `MEDIA_URL` in settings to something. Like:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: @MossaddakHossain please share settings. Last path (your media) in error is very weird and is a problem probably. Is the media url empty?

Answer (score 1):

Django urls need to have a trailing slash and the url you tried to access does not have it, check in your `settings.py` file if APPEND_SLASH is set to false

Among Django's many built-in features is APPEND_SLASH, which by default is set to True and automatically appends a slash / to URLs that would otherwise 404.

You can turn off this option by just setting `APPEND_SLASH = False`

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212122/why-django-urls-end-with-a-slash) about why django uses trailing slashes

Comment: Please don't guess. Without code there can be many possibilities for such error. And by default Django accepts such url.

Comment: This is an issue that has been nagging me for a while (I've already encountered 2 questions where this would have solved the problem).  Thanks, @JaimeOrtiz, for the extremely useful answer, which *should be the accepted answer*!

Answer (score 0):

You have the same admin path defined in your root urls.py and in your app.  It should probably be in just the root.  Remove it from:

```py
from os import name
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls), ##### REMOVE
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('singup', views.handle_singUp, name= "handle_singUp"),
    path('login', views.handle_login, name="handle_login"),
    path('logout', views.handle_logout, name="handle_logout"),
    path('contact', views.handle_contact, name="handle_contact"),
    path('frontend_orders', views.frontend_orders, name="frontend_orders"),
    path('hire_me', views.hire_me, name="hire_me")
]
```

**Edit**
After trying, and failing to reproduce the OP's error on my machine using *all* the answers given as of this writing, it turned out my original answer was not correct (not incorrect, but also not the solution), in fact the *original* answer given by Jaime Ortiz, was most likely the correct one.

But why was it so hard to come to this realization?  Within the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212122/why-django-urls-end-with-a-slash) he provided was this, which is why, when I initially tried his solution it did not work.  Below is from the answer provided by
All Іѕ Vаиітy in that link. Note that within the [] is my insertion.

> Since django observes both the urls [the one with the trailing slash
> and the one without] as different, if you are caching your app, Django
> will keep two copies for same page at ...

So either use `admin/` instead of `admin`, or apply `APPEND_SLASH = False` to your settings.py, **clear your browser cache** and then you can use either, Django will append the slash automatically.